# How to improve performance of application using DB queries?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance

I am a database person, I have a Java-based web application.

It is running slow, Developers reported me that due to DB only it is slow. They are asking to do query tuning.

I tried to tune the queries, but I am not able to gain much performance.

When I try to run the queries in a browser, it's working fine but in the application it is slow.

Please give me some suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Comment: you should consider asking specific problem/issue, and provide some details to understand the issue. Generalized job specific issue will not fetch you response on SO.

Comment: I dont known the problem they are simply blaming the queries.

Comment: *"Please give me the suggestion"* - profile the application, or get the developers to do it.

Comment: If they are blaming the queries, let them show you evidence. A profiler will show exactly how much time is spent in which part of the application.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would approach this:

- Let the developers pick one use case that's running slow and let them describe that to you. They should also mention all queries that run as part of that use case, including parameters.
- Show them the query results when you run them directly against the database from an SQL tool, not from the application. Make sure you use the same database instance and the same amount of data.
- If the times differ greatly, ask the developers to use a Java profiler (e.g. YourKit or visualVM) to identify where time is spent. This should make it easy to see bottlenecks.
- Be aware of the context when the application is slow. Is it for a single user, or when multiple users are executing the same use case?
- Most databases write log files as well, outlining query performance and highlighting problematic queries. Oracle's AWR files is an example, maybe MySQL has something similar.

Basically, try to work with the developers, not against them. Explain to them how you tuned the queries and let them show you how they try to tune the application. This approach has always worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your brief explanation.